# usb sound card no detected in raspberry pi zero w

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, usb, linux-device-driver, raspbian

I have raspberry pi zero W, running raspbian lite.
I'm trying to connect USB sound card.

the usb card is recognised by "dmesg" command but not added as sound card:

dmesg:

```
[   67.941583] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[   69.059664] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=48f0, 
     bcdDevice= 0.03
[   69.059715] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[   69.059743] usb 1-1.1: Product: USB Audio
[   69.059765] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Generic
[   69.080726] input: Generic USB Audio as /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1- 
     1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/0003:0BDA:48F0.0006/input/input10
[   69.142959] hid-generic 0003:0BDA:48F0.0006: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device 
[Generic USB Audio] on usb-20980000.usb-1.1/input0
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:48f0 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

play -l:  - no usb sound card

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****  
card 0: b1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1], device 0: bcm2835 HDMI 1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 8/8
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact problem on RPi4. Once I blacklisted the built-in sound card, following these instructions: https://www.instructables.com/Disable-the-Built-in-Sound-Card-of-Raspberry-Pi/
the usb sound card was recognized and it worked.